# Can anyone identify this small shrub? Has white flowers

Tags: species-identification, botany

Small shrub in adelaide south australia garden. [image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the common olive, *Olea europea*.  Cut into one of the fruits and see if there is a stone/pit, which will confirm.  You can search online for images to compare (use the Latin name as your search term).